# Trying to add dragging boundary to an image hidden on overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable

i'm trying to add boundary to this code where i could drag the image to see what parts are hidden without dragging it too much in a way where the background is visible 
which means when the lower boundary of the image for example reaches the lower boundary of the container it stops moving in that direction

```js
var offset = [0,0];
var mouse_is_down = false

function copie_click(elem, e) {
    mouse_is_down = true;
    offset = [elem.offsetLeft - e.clientX, elem.offsetTop - e.clientY];
}

function copie_unclick(elem, e) {
    mouse_is_down = false;
}

function copie_move(elem, e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // if this is removed mouse will unclick on move
    if (mouse_is_down) {
        elem.style.left = (e.clientX + offset[0]) + 'px';
        elem.style.top  = (e.clientY + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
}
```

```css
.mark_item_large {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.mark_item_image {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mark_item_image > img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 200%;
}
```

```html
        <div class="mark_item_large">
            <div class = "mark_item_image">
                <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/f844a81ff14743ba92ef5f4f498aa2c8.jpeg/v1/fill/w_940,h_495,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/f844a81ff14743ba92ef5f4f498aa2c8.webp" alt="copie preview" onmousedown="copie_click(this, event)" onmouseup="copie_unclick(this, event);" onmousemove="copie_move(this, event);">
            </div>
            .... other stuff here
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it my self by doing this !

```
function copie_click(elem, e) {
    mouse_is_down = true;
    offset = [elem.offsetLeft - e.clientX, elem.offsetTop - e.clientY];
}

function copie_unclick(elem, e) {
    mouse_is_down = false;
}

function copie_move(elem, e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); // if this is removed mouse will unclick on move
    if (mouse_is_down) {
        if ((e.movementX > 0 && e.target.offsetLeft < 0 ) || (e.movementX < 0 && -e.target.offsetLeft < (e.target.offsetWidth - e.target.parentElement.offsetWidth)))
            elem.style.left = (e.clientX + offset[0]) + 'px';
        if ((e.movementY > 0 && e.target.offsetTop < 0 )|| (e.movementY < 0 && e.target.offsetTop > -(e.target.offsetHeight - e.target.parentElement.offsetHeight) ) )
            elem.style.top  = (e.clientY + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
    disable_click = true;
}
```